# Why am I getting 'Uncaught TypeError: window[i] is not a function' when submitting authorize.net's AcceptUI form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authorize.net

I'm trying to use the authorize.net AcceptUI hosted form in a Vue.js component. https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Integrating_the_Hosted_Payment_Information_Form

The button to launch the form and the form show up correctly. After entering some test payment information and hitting submit, the form kind or reloads but doesn't disappear as it should. In the console I get the error AcceptUI.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: window[i] is not a function.

The relevant section of the AcceptUI script is this:

```
A = function(t) {
        "function" == typeof i ? i.call(null, t) : window[i](t)
    };
```

I have a responseHandler function defined. I'm not sure why it's not working. I stripped the code down to be almost identical to the sample that authorize.net provides but I'm assuming something with Vue.js or Typescript is interfering.

Please ignore any unrelated issues with the code. I'm only concerned about getting the responseHandler to work then I'll build out the rest of the functionality.

```
<template>
       <div>
         <form id="paymentForm" method="POST">
            <button type="button"
                    class="AcceptUI"
                    data-billingAddressOptions='{"show":true, "required":false}' 
                    data-apiLoginID="<redacted>" 
                    data-clientKey="<redacted>"
                    data-acceptUIFormBtnTxt="Submit" 
                    data-acceptUIFormHeaderTxt="Card Information" 
                    data-responseHandler="responseHandler">Pay
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component
export default class SubscriptionManager extends Vue {

  protected responseHandler(response: any) {
    console.log(response);
  }


  protected paymentFormUpdate(opaqueData: any) {
    const dataDescriptor: any = document.getElementById("dataDescriptor");
    dataDescriptor.value = opaqueData.dataDescriptor;
    const dataValue: any = document.getElementById("dataValue")
    dataValue.value = opaqueData.dataValue;

    // If using your own form to collect the sensitive data from the customer,
    // blank out the fields before submitting them to your server.
    const cardNumber: any = document.getElementById("cardNumber");
    cardNumber.value = "";

    const expMonth: any = document.getElementById("expMonth")
    expMonth.value = "";

    const expYear: any = document.getElementById("expYear")
    expYear.value = "";

    const cardCode: any = document.getElementById("cardCode")
    cardCode.value = "";

    const paymentForm: any = document.getElementById("paymentForm")
    paymentForm.submit();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem today. My problem was that the function named in data-responseHandler couldn't be found when it was time to execute the response callback. I had defined **data-responseHandler="authnetResponseHandler"** but forgot to define **function authnetResponseHandler(response)** before testing it.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Handling_the_Response